# 'New document' behaviour SharePoint 2013

Tags: document-library, content-type

I know this is something that is discussed a lot since previous versions of SharePoint, but I hope this is also something that can be easily solved since SharePoint 2013, but even with a lot of research, I don't know the answer yet.

When you have a new list, or a new document library in SharePoint, you always see the 'New Document' button on top. When you click on this, you have the 'Upload a document' option, and not the behaviour to use the default content type in the library. Is there any (maybe hidden) option to let this work and let this use the default content type?

Some things I already did:

- Add multiple content types and set a specific content type as default
- Set the default behaviour of the list to 'open in browser' or 'open in client' to maybe let this to the magic
- searched in the content type settings/configuration itself but nothing found

Any help or suggestions is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Davy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'New Document' on the top is part of the Web Part's tool bar. It points to Upload.aspx and you can't change it by modifying the settings but you can change the toolbar type of the web part from Full Toolbar to Show Toolbar or No Toolbar. To modify the web part's toolbar go to Edit Page -> Edit Web Part -> Toolbar Type.

With Show Toolbar you'll have 'New' on the top and it will open the default content type.
[image]

Another option is to use No Toolbar and add button on the page to open the content type you want with JavaScript([Programmatically trigger "New document" action in a document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89158/programmatically-trigger-new-document-action-in-a-document-library/89166#89166)).

Comment: cool! Thanks for the information. Again something I'll never forget.